# How to implement Transport-Client for running a website which uses ElasticSearch as database?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

**Goal:** Create a website which uses ElasticSearch to deliver its content.

**Problem:** There will be many users concurrently accessing the website.

**Options:**

1. Create and destroy a transport-client object for every request
2. Create a pool of transport-client objects which will be reused
3. Use a transport-client object as singleton

According to the [docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_transport_client_versus_node_client.html), a Node-Client is not an option for this scenario.

Technical background if it makes any difference: The website will be using Play Framework with Java. There will be a fancy JS frontend and it is expected that there will be many tiny AJAX HTTP requests harassing ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Transport Client as a singleton.

Comment: Could you elaborate why? Wouldn't this be blocking for other requests, if queries take a bit long?

Comment: @rapstacke Because the creator of ElasticSearch says so, see [link](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/What-is-your-best-practice-to-access-a-cluster-by-a-Java-client-tp4015311p4018507.html) and requests to the cluster are async and non-blocking. Avoid creating multiple TransportClients, because each spawns its own ThreadPool, growing with the number of nodes in the cluster. You can fiddle with the ThreadPool as shown here [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-transport-client-spawning-a-large-number-of-threads/526/2) - of course this is not in the docs.

Comment: I agree it's not super obvious in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html Well. I just `// on startup` to mean `on application startup` but may be it can be better than that. Would you like to open a PR?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean. I was talking about the unmentioned possible settings for the transport client's threadpool, which are not documented. See 2nd link of my 2nd comment here. Or here: [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-transport-client-spawning-a-large-number-of-threads/526/3)